# automatic ssh session when moving to mapped sshfs

Tags: ssh, sshfs

If you have a network drive mapped via sshfs, is there a way to automatically log on via ssh whenever changing to that directory?

```
$USER:$LOCALHOST:~: sshfs $USER:$REMOTEHOST /Volumes/dev0
$USER:$LOCALHOST:~: cd /Volumes/dev0
$USER:$REMOTEHOST:~
```

Comment: What does it have to do with programming?

Comment: Hey Eugene, You're right, I naively added this question here, I think it's more suited for SuperUser. (if I'm wrong with that where else would you recommend moving it to?) Also is there a way to move this to SuperUser without having to paste it (and consequently any answer).

Answer (score 1):

[Thomas Jansson provides a guide on integrating `sshfs` with `autofs`](http://www.tjansson.dk/?p=84). I'll summarize his guide here, so this answer will still be worth something if his site ever goes offline:

Create an `/etc/auto.master`:

```
/mnt/sshfs /etc/auto.sshfs uid=1000,gid=1000,--timeout=30,--ghost
```

Make sure your `uid` and `gid` match your userid and guid in `/etc/passwd` or whatever you use to provide system accounts.

Now add lines into `/etc/auto.sshfs`, one per desired filesystem, in the following form:

```
bar -fstype=fuse,rw,nodev,nonempty,noatime,allow_other,max_read=65536 :sshfs\#tjansson@bar.com\:
```

Be sure to change `tjansson@bar.com` to whatever user account and hostname you're going to be using. Change the leading `bar` to whatever you'd like the directory to be named. When you `cd /mnt/sshfs/bar`, `autofs` will automatically mount the FUSE filesystem for you. Of course, using SSH keys and the `ssh-agent(1)` will make this far more pleasant.

**Update**

> ... create a directory that literally logs you into the other machine.

Hey, that's pretty clever idea. You could either write a [shell function](http://www.talug.org/events/20030813/cmdline_tips_n_tricks_aug03.html) that checks the directory name you want to `cd` into and start a new `ssh` for you. Maybe you can (ab)use the [`PROMPT_COMMAND`](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prompt-HOWTO/x264.html) variable to `ssh` to the host if the directory name matches. Be warned that either approach *will* slow down your normal `cd` *or* every prompt display.

Another approach that I've used and enjoyed is a small little helper script, `~/bin/ssh-to`:

```
#!/bin/bash
hostname=`basename $0`
ssh $hostname $*
```

Symlink new names to this shell script: `ln -s ssh-to sarnold.org` and then you can run a command or log in on a remote site without typing the `ssh` all the time:

```
sarnold.org python foo.py
```

It'll log you in to whatever machine you've used for the name of the symbolic link and run whatever command you give it.

Comment: Hey Arnold, while this is sufficient for automating the mounting of the FS and it's great (thanks!), I was looking for a way to say create a directory that literally logs you into the other machine. Say you need to run a command on that machine (perhaps python bar/foo.py) you'll need a second terminal open to manage that.